# Unable to find the right .entry for a webscrape

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to get this code to spit out the "description" of the CVE but i can not get the actual description to print it keeps printing everything but the actual description.

```
import feedparser import csv import os

url = "https://www.tenable.com/cve/feeds?sort=newest" feed = feedparser.parse(url)

for entry in feed.entries: print("Entry Summary:", entry.description) print("\n")
```

Thiis the the output im getting for every line, i keep changing the entry value but thats till not working.

```
Entry Summary: <p>Critical Severity</p>
<h3>Description</h3>
<p>** REJECT ** This candidate is unused by its CNA.</p>
```

I have tried using all types of .entry values but nothing is grabbing the true details

For better format i have the images also

The code and output: https://imgur.com/SM6FU3S

The website I'm scraping https://imgur.com/OTyMNTM